# Dedicated web service for web app (Python/Django)

Tags: python, django, rest

Let's assume that I want to create a simple todo list web application. I am thinking about creating RESTful web services which will be used my the web application and which will be providing all functionalities concerning managing todo list and tasks. I have two concerns:

1. Is there a sense in creating dedicated web service assuming web service will be only used by my web application? Web service and web application will be on the same server and there have to be a lot of 'views' duplication. Web application will only delegate request to web service, process the response, and return a web page.
2. Assuming I decided for this kind of architecture: dedicated web service + web application, what is the best practice for calling web service from views in web application? They will be just two different apps within Django project. `request`?

Comment: You may create a seperate web service in two cases - first is when you want to consume the service using a frontend JS fromework like AngularJS and second is if in future you are going to have more clients (mobile/desktop applications) which will need to consume the same API.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So let's assume I will home more clients in the future. Now I want to create web application in Python/Django. Should I use standard HTTP request inside views to call the web service?

Comment: No, you should't do that, it will add unnecessary latencies. You could have the api and also have the webapp in the same django project. Or if you want to you can go with something like AngularJS

Comment: Ok, I understand. But there will be some code duplication and some views may look very similar in api and webapp.

Comment: Yes, that will happen, but still better than django itself consuming the API's

Comment: Ok, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

By creating dedicated API's will help you in future if you decide to build mobile application, that case no need to write new API's as you can consume your existing API's. By doing this your are not repeating your server side codes. Only have to write the client side code. And coming to performance only load time will be more as it has to load HTML, JS and CSS after subsequent requests will be more faster